# Keyboard layout and keyboard mapping differ

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my mid-2011 iMac. I set the keyboard layout to Canadian Multi (first part). If I check the layout on the screen, the mapping is correct. It is also correct in the symbols file (from usr/shared/X11/xkb/symbols).

But when I type, in any software, some keys are mixed up. For example, on my keyboard, there's a 'ù' between the left shift and the 'z' key. But it's showing up as '/'. The '/' key should be the one left to the '1' key, which shows up as 'ù'.

Any advice on how to apply correct mapping to my keyboard?

Thank you!